# Chat persistence in Live Agent

Tags: liveagent, chat

The Live Agent code is hosted in a specific page of the website. When the user goes/navigates to other page or refreshes the page, all the chat data is lost. The chat window shows "Start Chat" button. Is there a way to retain the data in the same chat session? If yes, how? 
 I have gone through the Live Agent Dev Guide and did not find any answer to the same.

Answer (score 0):

Store the data in cookies and read those cookies every time you initialize live agent.

Comment: What cookies should I store, and how should I initialize the live agent with specific cookies?